# have someone come or coming?

Tags: usage, present-participles, bare-infinitives, experiential-have

In the following, should "come" or "coming" be used? If only "come" is correct, why?
The first sentence comes from a news story relating to the oldest dog in the world.

> We've had a lot of journalists and people **come** from all over the world to take a picture with Bobi.

> We have orders **coming** in from all over the world.

Source: https://edition.cnn.com/2023/05/13/world/bobi-oldest-dog-31-birthday-trnd/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -ing form in your example sentence is a *present participle*, indicating something which is currently ongoing. So, they have orders which currently are coming from all over the world.

The **come** form would work too, though it does not come with the implication that those orders are appearing *now*. It implies instead that *generally* orders do appear from all over the world.

Similarly with the journalist example, it's explicitly talking about something which happened in the past rather than something which is happening right now.

> We have journalists *coming* from all over the world.

If you were to swap this for the present tense along with the present participle, the situation changes. It makes the reader think that journalists are *at this moment* on their way to have a photo taken.

So your choice here depends on whether something is happening, or is ongoing, at the time of speaking.